# Based on observable, choose observable out of an object of observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an object of observables and another observable that provides
a changing key.
I would like to construct an observable that switches between the
observables in the object based on that key.

Example:

```
// Choose randomly between "up" or "down" every second
const upOrDown$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).publish().refCount()
                    .map(() => Math.random() < 0.5 ? "up" : "down") 

const myMap =
  { "up"   : Rx.Observable.interval(100).publish().refCount().map("foo")
  , "down" : Rx.Observable.interval(100).publish().refCount().map("bar")
  }

upOrDown$.flatMap(ud => myMap[ud]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as intended. 
I would expect that for the duration of one second, **either** `foo` or `bar` is emitted and not both.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are never ending the previous sequences when a new one is generated. This will actually run correctly for the first second, but after that when the outer interval emits again the previous chain is not cancelled so you start receiving both of the streams. You are probably looking for `flatMapLatest` instead of `flatMap`. The former will dispose of the current inner stream as soon as a new event comes in from the outer one.

```
upOrDown$.flatMapLatest(ud => myMap[ud]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I don't actually know if your inner sources will be hot or cold, but if they are the latter you can also remove the `publish().refCount()` and replace it with `take(count)` instead, which would be another way of cutting off the stream.

Finally as a performance note, I would recommend that you put as much of your logic **before** you do `publish().refCount()` as only direct subscribers would receive the benefit of broadcasting in this case, adding the `map()` operator to the end of it means that under the hood you are implicitly creating a new `MapObservable` instance for each subscription that you make.